# Design a stack with operations on middle element

Tags: algorithm, stack, implementation

How to implement a stack which will support following operations in O(1) time complexity?

1. Push which adds an element to the top of stack.
2. Pop which removes an element from top of stack.
3. Find Middle which will return middle element of the stack.
4. Delete Middle which will delete the middle element

Comment: Circular doubly linked list with a sentinel node, pointer to the middle element, boolean storing whether the stack has an even number of elements.

Comment: Makes all of the special cases for deletion disappear.

Comment: In case of 2 elements, which one is the middle one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a LinkedList data structure with an extra pointer to the middle element.
Also, you need another variable `Var` to store whether  the LinkedList has an even or odd elements.

- Push which adds an element to the top of stack.

Add the element to the head of the LinkedList. Update the pointer to the middle element according to `Var`

- Pop which removes an element from top of stack.

Remove the head of the LinkedList. Update the pointer to the middle element according to `Var`

- Find Middle which will return middle element of the stack.

Use the pointer to the middle element

- Delete Middle which will delete the middle element

Copy next element's value to middle, remove next element. Here is a more detailed description: http://www.mytechinterviews.com/singly-linked-list-delete-node

Comment: why not array or list ? Java also uses internally array as implementation  for stack

Comment: using array, we won't be able to delete the middle element in O(1), because its in the middle and deleting it would require the rest to be shifted one position.

Comment: Stack => {top -> 1 -> 2 -> middle -> 3 -> 4 -> bottom} , for given Single LL like this how will you move the middle pointer to element 2 when element is pushed on top but every node next is pointing to downwards. So I believe this problem can be solved using DLL or modify the Single LL node structure to handle such scenario.

Answer (score 1):

Use a LinkedList datastructure with a pointer to head, tail, and middle elements.

This would give you the O(1) time complexity for pushing, popping, and deleting the middle elements as well as the search.

The only trick would be to move the "middle" element pointer correctly when adding or subtracting elements from this datastructure.

Comment: why not array or list ? Java also uses internally array as implementation for stack

Answer (score 0):

Here is the implementation based on array

```
/**
 * Stack implementation with 
 * push // push the element at top of stack
 * pop // removes and returns the element from top of stack
 * findMiddle // returns the element from middle of stack
 * deleteMiddle // deletes the element from middle of stack
 * @author manjeet
 * @param <E>
 */

public class Stack<E> {
  private final int size;
  private int top;
  private E[] elements;

  /**
   * Constructor with default size
   */
  public Stack() {
    this(10);
  }

  public Stack(int s) {
    size = s > 0 ? s : 10;
    top = -1;
    elements = (E[]) new Object[size]; 
  }

  /**
   * Push element e to stack if it is not full
   * @param e
   */
  public void push(E e) {
    if (top == size - 1){
     // if stack is full
        System.out.println("Stack is full, cannot push element " +  e);
    }else{
        elements[++top] = e; // place e on Stack
    } 
  }

  /**
   * pop element from the top of the stack if it is not empty
   * @return top of the stack
   */
  public E pop() {
    E e = null;
    if (top == -1){
     // if stack is empty
        System.out.println("Stack is empty, cannot pop");
    }else{
        e = elements[top--]; // remove and return top element of Stack
    } 
    return e;
  }

  /**
   * Give middle element of the stack if it is not empty
   * @return middle element of the stack
   */
  E findMiddle() {
      if (top == -1){
          System.out.println("Stack is empty, cannot pop");
          return null;
      }
      return elements[top/2];
  }

  /**
   * Delete middle element of the stack if it is not empty
   * @return middle element of the stack
   */
  E deleteMiddle(){
      if (top == -1){
          System.out.println("Stack is empty, cannot pop");
          return null;
      }
      int index = (int)top/2;
      E middle = elements[index];
      System.arraycopy(elements, index+1 , elements, index, (top-index));
      top--;
      return middle;
  }

  public static void main(String args[]) {

      Stack<Integer> stack = new Stack<Integer>();
      stack.push(1);
      stack.push(2);
      stack.push(3);
      stack.push(4);
      stack.push(5);
      stack.push(6);
      stack.push(7);

      System.out.println("deleted=" + stack.deleteMiddle());
      System.out.println("middle=" + stack.findMiddle());
      System.out.println("popped=" + stack.pop());



    }
}
```